# problem using select : "//somenode"

Tags: xslt, xpath

Hey everyone im trying to use

```
<xsl:for-each select="//node1">
```

in my xsl the problem is that it gets all the nodes name node1 together and not passing them one by one (as for each should be)
just for you to know im using // pattern becuase my xml changes and i do need to find inside some node the node1

hope you can help...

Comment: This doesn't jive with my experience. Why do you think you are getting them together? The error might be elsewhere.

Comment: hmmm well it is nested select
i have something like for-each inside for-each so basically if im not mistaken it should get all the "node1" inside the parent for-each but it not and its bringing all the "node1" nodes in all the xml...

Comment: and i think that because i concatenate the values of the "node1" that I've pulled

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="//node1">
```

It is hard to say why you are seeing the issue that you are seeing as a `for-each` should work just fine but it is often better to use the declarative approach to coding in XSLT (as I have shown above) as opposed to the more procedural `for-each`.

**Edit:** Okay - I think I see what is going on now.

Try this:

```
<another-att>
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraph/text">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 0">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@textvalue"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</another-att>
```

Comment: well in this example i guess it would work but in my real xml it won't becuase i have more children until you get to paragraph/text ...
and im working with alot of xml files and the wat into paragraph/text may be diffrent...

Comment: i thought about doing something like
for-each on the another-att
and then use for-each with //text
but it gives me the same result....

Comment: ok found the answer....
just added "." before the "//text" and it works
thanks anyway